# Отрезать миллисекунды от TimeSpan

Tags: c#, mediaplayer, wpf, строки

Доброго времени суток, Хэшкод.

Есть у меня приложение, в котором с помощью WPF-овского MediaElement реализован простой медиа плеер.

Есть label, который показывает текущее время видео. Я его забираю так:

```
mainVideoScreen.labelCurrentTime.Content = (TimeSpan.FromSeconds(videoPanel1.MEVideo.Position.TotalSeconds)).ToString();
```

где MEVideo это MediaElement. Ну и разумеется, этот код находится в tick-е.

Это даст текст вида: часы.минуты.секунды.миллисекунды

Вопрос в том, как отрезать оттуда миллисекунды. С полным временем такого трабла не было, т.к. я его тупо достал средствами DirectShow из метаданных и немного пошаманил. А как тут это сделать - не впилю.

З.Ы. Как видно из кода, тут идет комбинирование WPF и WinForms, просьба не ругаться на это :)

Comment: *Небольшое замечание:*

- `MediaElement.Position` и так имеет тип `TimeSpan`, поэтому ваш код имеет семантику `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TimeSpan.TotalSeconds)`, что бессмысленно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

да, именно так:

```
TimeSpan ts;
String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
            ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
            ts.Milliseconds / 10);
```

пуличте примерно такой вариант: 00:00:51.91

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте форматирующую строку "d.hh:mm:ss"

Answer (score 0):

В моем случае помог весьма примитивный способ.

`TimeStamp.ToString().Substring(0,8);`